# Merge tables to a single table

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, erb

Relevant snippets

Show.html.erb

```
<% outbound_messages.each do |outbound_message| %>
        <h5>Outbound Message</h5>
        <%= render "trace/display_tabular_data", :data => outbound_message %>
    <% end %>
```

Display_tabular_data.html.erb

```
<table border="1px solid black">
  <thead>
  <tr>
    <%data.each do |key,value|%>
        <th><%=key.capitalize%></th>
    <%end%>
  </tr></thead><tr>
  <%data.each do |key,value|%>
      <td><%=value%></td>
  <%end%>
</tr>
</table>
```

So what happens is that each row of data, gets printed in a unique table. 
So one has something like https://i.stack.imgur.com/0x4rA.jpg

But clearly a much better result would be as a single table  (Desired outcome)

```
Outbound Message
Message ID, Exchange, Relayed
Row1
Row2
Row3
Row4
...
....
```

Any ideas how I can go about this? Display_tabular_data is called at-least 15 times in different places in show.html.erb, so it would be much easier if it was somehow possible to get this final result by making changes only in display_tabular_data, and not in show.html.erb. If not possible, please give me the best possible way?

Comment: The code in your 'show.html.erb' repeats twice. Is that intentional?

Comment: Does every outbound_message have the same set of keys?

Comment: @Charles - Yes, every outbound_message has the same set of keys. Click the picture link for a sample result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to render a separate table for every object, how about something like this in show.html.erb:

```
<% unless outbound_messages.empty? %>
  <%= render 'trace/display_tabular_data', :data => outbound_messages %>
<% end %>
```

And then in the partial:

```
<h5>Outbound Messages</h5>

<table border="1px solid black">
  <thead>
  <tr>
    <% data.first.each do |key,value| %>
      <th><%=key.capitalize%></th>
    <% end %>
  </tr>
  </thead>

  <% data.each do |outbound_message| %>
    <tr>
    <% outbound_message.each do |key,value|%>
        <td><%=value%></td>
    <% end %>
    </tr>
</table>
```

This only works if you are confident that every outbound_message has the same set of keys.

Comment: Exactly my thoughts, but this require changes in show.rb as well. But a pretty good solution nevertheless.

Comment: You're going to have to change show.html.erb to achieve what you want, which is a new single row in a table for each object in the outbound_messages collection.

Comment: However, if you want to minimize the impact to show.html.erb, you could pass the whole outbound_messages collection to the partial instead of just a single record.

Comment: I am gonna be doing the 2nd for sure...Should have thought about it before I almost finished my application rather than now. But thanks anyways.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go..

```
<% if outbound_messages.count > 0 %>
  <h5>Outbound Message</h5>
    <table border="1px solid black">
      <thead>
        <tr>
        <td>Message ID</td>
        <td>Exchange</td>
        <td>Relayed</td>
      </tr>
      </thead>
      <% outbound_messages.each do |outbound_message| %>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <%= outbound_message[:message_id] %>
          </td>
          <td>
            <%= outbound_message[:exchange] %>
          </td>
          <td>
            <%= outbound_message[:relayed] %>
          </td>
        </tr>
      <% end %> 
    </table>
<% end %>
```

You can eliminate the partial entirely

Comment: My initial approach a few days back was something like this, but there are way too many keys to type it out like this. I have outbound message, orders, reservation etc, hence this method just doesn't work.